# Operating Systems: Process Creation

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

What does this statement in the context of process creation mean?

"In UNIX, the child's initial address space is a copy of the parent's, but there are definitely two distinct address spaces involved; no writable memory is shared".

I do understand that after the fork system call, the parent process is cloned and that clears the copied part. What I find difficult understanding is the "different address spaces" part, after the address space is copied.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

"Different address spaces" just means that the two processes have separate and independent copies of all their data in memory.  Initially those copies are the same, but each process can change data in its own memory and the changes are not visible to the other process.  For example, if the initial process has a variable called `x` stored at address `0x01234567`, after the `fork()` both processes will have a variable at that address, but they're different variables that can hold different values despite having the same address.  An address like `0x01234567` actually corresponds to different places in RAM in each process.

If both processes shared the same address space, they'd both be looking at the *same* memory (rather than separate and independent copies of it), so changes made by one process would be visible to the other.  An address like 0x01234567 would refer to the same spot in RAM in both processes.

(In principle, `fork()` makes a complete copy of all the calling process's memory.  In practice, the copying is typically deferred, using a technique called "copy-on-write" that allows the system to avoid making duplicate copies of data that's the same in both processes.  But that's an implementation detail that's basically invisible to applications; the system behaves *as if* `fork()` made a complete copy of everything.)

Comment: The translation of that virtual address would be the same. The only difference is that after fork all entries in page table are marked as Read-Only, along side another flag to indicate a "Copy-on-Write". Then, when one process attempts to write, the page is copied.

Comment: Thank You TonyTannous and Wyzard. Made it much clearer!

Answer (score 0):

In linux there is a concept of COW (Copy On Write). When a fork() is called the child process will be created. The child and parent process will have there own address space. The child process clones the address space of parent (including stack and heap). But it is required to know when the cloning will happen. If the parent has stack memory of say 100 bytes and the child process does not modify that memory (or simply reads) through out it's life span then the stack memory of 100 bytes will not be cloned. Only when the child process tries to write to that memory the memory will be cloned. This functionality in linux is called COW.